# Function of process that starts logarithmic and ends linear

Tags: functions

I am observing data from a process that seems to start logarithmically, but becomes linear at a certain point. Is there a function that describes this behavior?

Additionally, If I fit a curve to these observations using that function, how can I find the point at which the process switches from logarithmic to linear?

Example of observed data (blue) and best fit (orange) using `curve_fit` Python's `scipy.optimize` library with the function `y = a * np.exp(-b * x) + c`

[image]

UPDATE:

I find that the relationship does fit the power law. Plotting $y = ax^b$ on a log-log scale.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried $O(n \log n)$ functions?

Comment: You could try fitting functions like $\log(x+1) + x$ with some parameters in appropriate places (log grows much slower than linear, so this "becomes linear" in a sense). But this is just picking a function out of a hat -- if you have domain knowledge that can help you choose a function to fit, that would be good.

Comment: Have you first tried something simple such as a power law $y=ax^p$? Plot your data on a semi-log scale and see if it looks like a straight line.

Comment: I meant log-log scale.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Thank you, my data does follow the power law (see update)